# Can we shorten explanatory "that is" to "that's" in speech and writing?

Tags: grammaticality

I've never seen or heard the *explanatory* "**that is**" shortened to "**that's**", but it wouldn't hurt to be sure if it's possible or not

> When you recount a story, you can either use past or present tenses, but consistency is key. **That is**, if you choose present tenses, for instance, to portray some of the events of a story set in the past, then you should stick with present tenses for the entire story.

Comment: No, but you could use `thus` instead.

Comment: You cannot shorten away syllables that have emphasis.

Comment: How about a `so` instead?

Answer (score 10):

No, you cannot shorten it. The explanatory *that is* as here:

> **That is**, if you choose present tenses, ...

is the anglicised latin ***id est***, which is usually itself abbreviated to ***ie*** or ***i.e.***

> **i.e.** if you choose present tenses, ...

As such, this usage of *that is* is a grammatical construction and should not be shortened.

So, while in general text and speech you can shorten *that is* to *that's* with an apostrophe to denote the missing letter in the contraction, you cannot shorten an explanatory *that is*.

Comment: That is, that's one way to destroy intelligibility.

Comment: Except that the explanatory "that is" is very often contracted to "that's" in informal speech and writing. ;

Comment: I think the conclusion is right, but the reasoning is totally wrong.  The right answer is, (as @MrLister said in a comment to the question), because you can't abbreviate syllables which are emphasized.

Comment: @charmer Really? Can you give an example?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz try here https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=13&ved=0ahUKEwjan9i2t77XAhUH0hoKHa3UBLEQFghyMAw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bbc.co.uk%2Fprogrammes%2Fp018pxzq%2Fp018pyx7&usg=AOvVaw3UISU4yZvJkhQIt8gHxRO5 or simply search for the phrase "That's because".

Comment: @MartinBonner - any supporting evidence for 'you can't abbreviate syllables which are emphasized."  Is that not what you just did with "can't"?.

Comment: @charmer : I don't have supporting evidence, but no, it is not what I did with "can't".  That would be spoken (at least in my British English accent) as "car-nt".  If I were speaking, and wished to emphasise the "not"  - as in "You can *not* abbreviate..." - I would have written it like that.